# JTextArea blocks thread on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, swing

I have a GUI app with `JTextArea` component. It is used to log some info:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow {

    private JTextArea myTextArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainWindow();
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        myTextArea = new JTextArea();

        mainFrame.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
        mainFrame.add(myTextArea);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i=0; i< 100; i++)
            log("Minimal, Complete, Verifable!");
    }

    private void log(String message) {
        myTextArea.append(message);
    }
}
```

It works ok on Windows 7. However, on Linux it seems to hang the whole app after a few calls. Analysis of the stack reveals that GUI thread is in a `BLOCKED` state:

```
"Thread-4" prio=10 tid=0x00007f68e8a63000 nid=0xce7 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f68f0b40000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.awt.Component$AccessibleAWTComponent.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:9445)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007980597e8> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent$AccessibleJComponent.getLocationOnScreen(JComponent.java:3670)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$AccessibleJTextComponent.caretUpdate(JTextComponent.java:2608)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.fireCaretUpdate(JTextComponent.java:407)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$MutableCaretEvent.fire(JTextComponent.java:4415)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$MutableCaretEvent.stateChanged(JTextComponent.java:4437)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.fireStateChanged(DefaultCaret.java:802)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.changeCaretPosition(DefaultCaret.java:1277)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.handleSetDot(DefaultCaret.java:1173)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.setDot(DefaultCaret.java:1154)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret$Handler.insertUpdate(DefaultCaret.java:1726)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:202)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:749)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:708)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
    at javax.swing.JTextArea.append(JTextArea.java:477)
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: @Kao How serious is your comment?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am the user of this site, too and I often deal with questions which you may call 'incomplete' but then I don't discuss on how to extend an example, but instead try to help answering it.
Anyway, I modified the question and added a **complete** example. Just copy-paste it, ok? I would be grateful for an **actual** help.

Comment: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Then use a `Timer` to space out the calls to `log()` like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37922288/261156).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @trashgod have written in comment, GUI objects should be manipulated only on the event dispatch thread. One can achieve this using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

This is a fixed code of `log()` method, which solved the problem:

```
private void log(final String message) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            infoTextArea.append(LogUtils.formatLogMessage(message));
        }
    });
}
```